# Angular Momentum with Upper Index

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I am asked to show $[L^2,L_i] = 0 $, but with the definition :

$L^2 \equiv L_i L^i$

I tried this:

$[L_i L^i,L_i] = L_i [L^i,L_i] + [L_i,L_i]L^i$

We know that : $[L_i,L_i]$ = 0 , so we have,

$[L_i L^i,L_i] = L_i [L^i,L_i]$.

So I could not understand this term with upper index. What is $L^i$ ?? Any clues?

Comment: You can't reuse the $i$ index here. The $i$'s in $L^2 = L_i L^i$ are dummy indices, since they are repeated. But the $i$ in the $L_i$ (in the commutator) is an open index. So you should relabel the dummy index, i.e. write $L^2 = L_j L^j$ or any other letter you like. If you're not happy with repeated indices, you can also write $L^2 = \delta_{jk} L^j L^k$ for example. Good luck.

Comment: Ok. But I think I dont know the difference between $L_i$ and $L^i$. $L_1$ is the x component of angular momentum vector. What is $L^1$?

Comment: Just the same as $L_1$. You're not working with relativistic theories here, and even in special relativity (taking the metric $-\; +\; +\; +$) you can raise or lower spacelike indices at will.

Comment: Well numerically they are the same (for the reason you state). But they transform differently under a coordinate change. However, OP, that's a standard story - $L^i$ is a vector in 3-space, whereas $L_i$ is a covector. In some first- or second-year course you must have seen the difference.